# How to protect a shared resource from both user processes and kernel processes simultaneously?

Tags: linux, operating-system, locking

How to protect a shared resource from both user processes and kernel processes simultaneously?. It's rare and very corner case. I have been asked this query in an interview. 
TIA

Comment: You can't protect anything from the kernel. It has control over everything.

Comment: You can try to mark the pages of the resource (assuming it is a memory resource) inaccessible. I suppose this must be done in kernel, as the userspace permissions might not affect the kernel.

Comment: @Linuxios, This is is general statement. But in general, we are using couple of locking mechanisms(of course, under co-operative environment only) like spin locks, semaphores, mutexs, may be using some condtional signals etc.. My query is related(limited) to this context only. Thanks

Comment: I think this kind of interview question is a candidate for "I don't understand, can you explain what _exactly_ you want to achieve?". As Linuxios said, you cannot really "protect" (or hide) anything from the kernel. Unless the kernel runs in a VM and you can control the host, the endeavour is kind of stupid (and in that case, the "kernel" is more like a user process than a kernel). On the other hand, the meaning of "protecting" might be about concurrently accessing a resource such as a port or a block device correctly (atomically). You just have to know what they really want.

Comment: @kannah: I ment that if the kernel *isen't* cooperating with you, it can still access anything it wants. That's all I ment.

Comment: @Damon: Let's forget about it's an interview question and assume that kernel runs in VM only. Could we have a reasonable solution

Comment: "Can you explain what _exactly_ you want to achieve"(!). As stated before, the OS kernel "owns" the computer and all resources, you are at its mercy. It is certainly possible to get the OS to cooperate within some limits to prevent haphazard corruption (if that is what "protect" means for you), but without a rootkit (or a patched kernel, which is somehow the same thing) there is no way you can prevent the OS from taking away, deleting, terminating "anything you own", including your entire process, whenever it wants. It won't normally do that without a good reason, but it nevertheless _can_.

Comment: a semaphore is your resort, use a semaphore to protect a resource from user space and "kernel" context of a "process".

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can be done by several way.
One such way is

***System Call***
Create two system call, one to acquire a lock and one to release a lock. If user process wants to access the shared resource, it would call the acquire-lock system call. If the system call successfully returns, user process can access the shared resource. When user process is done it would release the lock, by calling the release system call. The system calls itself acquire a release a `spinlock_t` or `mutex_t`(or any other locking mechanism). The kernel processes that wants to access the shared resource has to acquire the same lock using `spin_lock/spin_unlock` or `mutex_lock/mutex_unlock`.

As pointed out by @Damon this is very generic questions, and you should be asking specific question to the interview inorder to give a concrete answer.